# Show $1/X_t^2$ is bounded where $X_t$ is a random process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Assume $X_0=1$ and $X_{t+1} = X_t + I_t$, where $\{I_t\}_{t=1}^\infty$ are i.i.d Bernoulli trials with $p=1/2$. In detail,
$$
\mathbb{P}(I_t=1) = \mathbb{P}(I_t=0) = \frac{1}{2}. 
$$
We want to show that for any $\delta>0$ and $t\in \mathbb{N}$, there is a constant $C$ independent of $t$ such that
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} <C \right) \ge 1-\delta.
$$

---

The intuition is that $\mathbb{E}( X_t)= \frac{t}{2}+1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} \approx  \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{c}{t^2}$, which is bounded. I hope to generalize this to a stochastic process.

---

Thank you for your answers! I'm wondering if we can show this is subgaussian? I checked the simulation result and it's definitely subgaussian.

Here is a histogram of 10000 samples after 10000 iterations:

[image]

Comment: It's probably a good idea to pose a new question about showing it is subgaussian. This will help keep the answers aligned with the original question. It will also give you a chance to give the specific definition of "subgaussian" you have in mind.

Comment: I think I figured it out. It's best to use the geometric distribution here. Consider J_n = {X_t| X_t=n}. Then |J_n| follows a geometric distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to try and provide a very explicit answer to your question. The main trick is to give an upper bound expression that is in general much easier to work with.

To start let $t \in \mathbb{N}$ and define the *random* sets for $n=1,2,...$
$$J_n = \{ i \in \{1,2,...,t\} : n^2 \leq X_i < (n+1)^2 \}$$
Let $n^*$ denote the be the first index such that $(n^*+1) > t$. The reason we want to do this is because it gives us the following bounds
\begin{align}
    \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} &= \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \sum_{i \in J_n} \frac{1}{X_i^2} \\
    &\leq \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \sum_{i \in J_n} \frac{1}{(n^2)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{|J_n|}{n^4}.
\end{align}
The first equality uses that the set $(J_n)$ are a partition of $\{1,2,...t\}$. The inequality is using that if $X_i \in J_n$ then $X_i \geq n^2$ and therefore $\frac{1}{X_i^2} \leq \frac{1}{(n^2)^2}$. The last equality is just counting terms. Importantly since $(n^* + 1)^2 > t$ we are guaranteed that the set $\{1,...,t\}$ is contained in the sets $J_1,...,J_{n^*}$ (although some of these sets may be empty).

Now since this always holds we have for every $C$
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}\left ( \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} \geq C \right ) \leq 
    \mathbb{P}\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{|J_n|}{n^4} \geq C \right ).
\end{equation}
This is pretty good progress so far. The next thing I am going to do is apply [Markov's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) and obtain
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}\left ( \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{|J_n|}{n^4} \geq C \right ) \leq \frac{1}{C}\mathbb{E} \left [ \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{|J_n|}{n^4} \right ] = \frac{1}{C}\sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{1}{n^4}\mathbb{E}[|J_n|].
\end{equation}
The next task is to estimate $\mathbb{E}[|J_n|]$. One thing that makes this a bit tricky as that sometimes the sets $J_n$ are completely empty (for example if $X_t < n^2$) and sometimes the sequence ends while the set $J_n$ is in progress (if $X_t \in (n^2, (n+1)^2)$) and we need to address these cases.

To handle this, consider the infinite sequence $(I_n')$ such that for $i=1,...,t$ we have $I_i = I_i'$ and for $i > t$ the variables $I_i'$ are independent (of everything) and $\mathbb{P}(I_i' = 1) = \mathbb{P}(I_i' = 0) = 1/2$ and let $X_{t+1}' = X_{t}' + I_t'$ with $X_{1}' = 1$.

Now consider the sets
\begin{equation}
    J_n' = \{i \in \mathbb{N} : n^2 \leq X_i' < (n+1)^2\}.
\end{equation}
The important point of doing this whole thing is that $|J_n| \leq |J_n'|$ for every $n$.

To see this note that if $X_t \geq (n+1)^2$ then $J_n = J_n'$ (since for the first $t$ variables $I_i = I_i'$ and therefore $X_i = X_i'$). Also if $|J_n| = 0$ then the claim is immediate because $|J_n'| \geq 0$. The last case is when $n^2 \leq X_t < (n+1)^2$. In this case $J_n \subset J_n'$ since the $X_i = X_i'$ on the indices leading up to $t$, and then we may possibly continuing adding further indices to the set $J_n'$.

To be frank, the previous argument is a bit annoying but handling edge case behaviors often is, especially when indexing is involved!

Overall we have shown that $|J_n| \leq |J_n'|$ for every $n=1,...,n^*$ and therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[|J_n|] \leq \mathbb{E}[|J_n'|].$$
Now let's estimate the sizes of $|J_n'|$. The general idea is that $|J_n'|$ can be modeled as counting coin flips problem. Since $J_n'$ is essentially the indices $I_i'$ that are required to increase $X_i$ from $n^2$ to just under $(n+1)^2$. This argument is a bit tricky.

Suppose that $k$ is the first index where $X_i' = n^2$ so that $k$ is the smallest index in $J_n$, that is to say
\begin{equation}
     X_k' = \sum_{i=1}^k I_i' = n^2
\end{equation}
The first index $\ell > k$ which is *nt* contained in $J_n'$ happens the first time
\begin{align}
    X_\ell' &= \sum_{i=1}^{\ell} I_i' = (n+1)^2 \\
    \iff \sum_{i=1}^\ell I_i' - \sum_{i=1}^k I_i' &= (n+1)^2 - n^2 \\
    \iff \sum_{i=k+1}^\ell I_i' &= 2n + 1
\end{align}
Notice that $\sum_{i=k+1}^\ell I_i'$ counts the number of "+1"s we observe in the run from $k+1$ to $\ell$. Therefore we will have $|J_n'| = \ell - k$. Now here is where we get into coin counting. The size of the gap $\ell - k$ is equivalent to the number of trials $I_i'$ before $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n + 1$ of them come up as $+1$. This is equivalent to the question of

> How many times will I need to flip a coin before I see heads $2n+1$ times?

The expected number of flips before seeing a certain number of heads has been answered many times online ([see here for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426171/expected-number-of-flips-until-kth-head)) and it turns out that the expected number of flips to see $K$ heads for any $K \in \mathbb{N}$ is $2K$ (when the probability of heads is 1/2) and we are using $K = 2n+1$. Since we need an extra one for the index $X_k$ which is in our set but does not count as a flip we get
$$\mathbb{E}|J_n'| = 4n + 2 + 1 = 4n + 3$$
This also applies to the edge case $|J_1'|$ as well. Overall we have reached the bound
\begin{align}
    \mathbb{P}\left ( \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} \geq C \right ) &\leq \frac{1}{C}\sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{1}{n^4}\mathbb{E}[|J_n|'] \\
    &= \frac{1}{C} \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4}.
\end{align}
Therefore using the complement rule we have
\begin{equation} 
    \mathbb{P} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} < C \right ) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{C} \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4}
\end{equation}
Now to have $\delta = \frac{1}{C} \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4}$ means setting $C = \frac{1}{\delta} \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4}$. Doing so we have
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} < \frac{1}{\delta} \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4} \right ) \geq 1 - \delta.
\end{equation}
Now the last piece of the puzzle is that $\sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4}$ still depends on $t$ because $n^*$ is chosen to be the smallest natural number such that $t < (n^*+1)^2$. We can make this hold for all $t \in \mathbb{N}$ by using
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{n=1}^{n^*} \frac{4n+3}{n^4} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{n^3} + \frac{3}{n^4} \leq 5 + 4 = 9
\end{equation}
where the bounds I use are that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3} < 5/4$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^4} < 4/3$. Overall this gives the fairly nice bound valid for all $t$ and $\delta$
$$
\mathbb{P} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_i^2} < 9/\delta \right ) > 1 - \delta
$$
and the $C = 9/\delta$ is completely independent of $t$ as required.

---

Just some closing notes.

- The methods I used here aren't optimized at all. They can definitely be substantially improved by choosing the sets $J_n$ a bit differently or by using a different tail bound than Markov's inequality (for example Chebyshev or Chernoff)
- The real mess of the proof comes with arguing the upper bounds on $|J_n|$. It's actually funny that if you do an infinite sum then the argument gets quite a bit cleaner.
- The proof I gave above actually can be used to show that the same bound holds (with a different constant than 9) if the $I_i \sim \text{Bern}(p)$ for any $p \in (0,1]$. The only change is the expected size of $|J_n'|$ from $4n + 3$ to $\frac{2n + 1}{p} + 1$.
- I would love to see someone go through the effort of getting a nice, explicit, tail bound of the form
  $$\mathbb{P} \left ( \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_t} - \mathbb{E} \sum_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{X_t} > \delta \right ) \leq e^{-\alpha \delta}$$
  or something close to it (I'm not sure what is precisely possible though).

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_i=1+I_1+\cdots+I_i$ and that
$\frac{1}{X_i^2}=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-sX_i}s\, ds,$ you can easily prove that for $S=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{X_i^2}\leq \infty$ we have $E(S)<\infty.$ The monotone convergence theorem implies that $\Pr(S<\infty)=1.$

Answer (score 1):

SLLN shows that

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t^2}{X_t^2}
= \left( \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{X_t}{t} \right)^{-2}
= (\mathbf{E}[I_1])^{-2} \in (0, \infty) \qquad \text{a.s.} $$

Hence, Limit Comparison Test with $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i^2} < \infty$ shows that $S := \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{X_i^2}$ converges almost surely. Then it is straightforward to establish OP's claim using this.